# There exists a prime congruent to $m$ mod $p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Q: Is every element of $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ represented by a prime number? More generally, let $m, n \in \mathbb Z$ be coprime. Is there a prime number congruent to $m$ modulo $n$?

the affirmative answer is given by [Dirichlet's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions).

> A: Yes, in fact there are infinitely many such primes.

I don't want to prove Dirichlet's theorem. Is it obvious that there always exists at least one such prime?

Comment: no, it is not obvious. True, though.

Comment: @WillJagy Is there a faster way to prove this, or is it considered a corollary of Dirichlet's theorem?

Comment: I find this an interesting question. It would seem that proving there is only one *should* be easier that proving that there are an infinite number.

Comment: The great majority of number theory constructions that I have ever seen require one such prime. The great American number theorist, Leonard Eugene Dickson, hated Dirichlet's theorem and all those methods. He did what he could to never use it in his 1939 book, Modern Elementary Theory of Numbers. In the end, though, he needed it. He did ask someone else to write the appendix with the proof, he couldn't stand the idea.

Comment: There we go, the appendix, pages  269-305 so pretty long, was written by W. T. Reid.

Comment: @WillJagy Wow, what an interesting anecdote! Thank you, I think that answers the question to my satisfaction.

Comment: @martycohen glad I'm not the only one with that feeling!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't want to prove Dirichlet's theorem. Is it obvious that there always exists at least one such prime?

It is not obvious, and in fact the claim "if $\gcd(m, n) = 1$ then there is at least one prime congruent to $m \bmod n$" is equivalent to the claim "if $\gcd(m, n) = 1$ then there are infinitely many primes congruent to $m \bmod n$."

The implication $\Leftarrow$ is obvious. To prove the implication $\Rightarrow$, suppose we want to prove that there are infinitely many primes congruent to $m \bmod n$. We can do this by using the existence of

- at least one prime congruent to $m \bmod n$
- at least one prime congruent to $m + n \bmod 2n$
- at least one prime congruent to $m + 2n \bmod 3n$

etc. This produces a sequence $p_k$ of primes congruent to $m + kn \bmod (k+1)n$, which gives a sequence of primes congruent to $m \bmod n$ where $p_k \to \infty$ and so the sequence $p_k$ contains infinitely many primes.

Comment: Thanks Qiaochu!

Comment: A slight problem is $m+n$ and $2n$ aren’t coprime if $m$ and $n$ are odd. If one uses $m+n$ mod $n^2$ (and then $m+n^2$ mod $n^3$ and so on) I think this issue goes away. In other words, $m+n^i$ mod $n^k$ for $i = 1,\ldots,k-1$ should give $k-1$ distinct (even mod $n^k$) primes congruent to $m$ mod $n$, for any $k$.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to prove some cases without Diriclet's Theorem for $ax+b$ with $a$ and $b$ coprime. Without going into too much deatail for the proofs, they are:

any integer $a$ and $b=1, -1$

$a=2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12, 24$ and $b$ is coprime to $a$

If you are given forms $ax+b$ and $ax+c$, say, it is also possible to prove that there are infintely many primes of the form $ax+b$ OR $ax+c$ (but does not prove the form individually). This happens exactly when $b^4=1\pmod a$ and $b^3=c\pmod a$.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is inspired by Qiaochu's idea, with a small correction mentioned in the comments there. Call the statement below ${\bf P}(q)$:

> If $(m,n) = 1$ then there exist $q$ distinct primes congruent to $m\ \text{mod } n$.

The goal is to show that ${\bf P}(1) \implies {\bf P}(\infty)$ by repeatedly applying ${\bf P}(1)$ to higher and higher multiples of $n$, with different lifts of $m$.

---

To makes this work, one must find numbers of the form $m + \ell$ for which $n\, |\, \ell$ and which are coprime to some large multiple of $n$. This will be done using the following (obvious) fact:

> Let $m$ and $n$ be coprime, let $\ell \geq 1$, and let $N$ be a multiple of $n$ which is also coprime to $m$. Then $m+\ell$ is coprime to $N$ if $\text{rad}(N)\, |\, \ell$.

In particular, the numbers $m_i := m + n^i$ are coprime to $n^{k+1}$ for each $i \in [1,k]$. Applying ${\bf P}(1)$ to each $m_i$, one finds $k$ distinct primes congruent to $m$ mod $n$, deducing ${\bf P}(k)$.

${\bf P}(1) \implies {\bf P}(k)$ for any $k \in \mathbb N$, so ${\bf P}(\infty)$ follows.